# IO Error when uploading file in IE9, works in IE10, Safari, Chrome and Firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following webservice to uploading a file using fineupload

```
   public class UploadHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            var svc = new DropzoneService();

            var request = context.Request;
            var formUpload = request.Files.Count > 0;

            var xFileName = request.Headers["X-File-Name"];
            var qqFile = request["qqfile"];

            var dzid = request.Params["dzid"].ToString().Replace(",", String.Empty);
            var rootid = request.Params["rootid"].ToString().Replace(",", String.Empty);

            var formFilename = formUpload ? request.Files[0].FileName : null;

            var filename = xFileName ?? qqFile ?? formFilename;
            var inputStream = formUpload ? request.Files[0].InputStream : request.InputStream;

            var filePath = Path.Combine(context.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Queue"), filename);
            using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite(filePath))
            {
                inputStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }

            svc.AddFile(filePath, Int32.Parse(dzid), Int32.Parse(rootid));

            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.Response.Write("{\"success\":true}");
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return true; }
        }
    }
```

It works great in all browsers except Internet Explorer 8 and 9, but in Internet Explorer 10 it works.

This is the exception
IO Exception The process could not access file C:\Users\user\Desktop\file.pdf because it in use by another process. (translated exception from swedish)

Answer (score 0):

I believe in IE 9 and below you always need to use request.Files[0].InputStream even for a single file upload.

so your code should be something more like ...

```
decimal browserVer;

decimal.TryParse(context.Request.Browser.Version, out browserVer);

var inputStream = context.Request.Files.Count > 1 || ( context.Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "IE" && browserVer < 10 ) ? context.Request.Files[0].InputStream : context.Request.InputStream;
```

presuming of course you are only reading the first file ...